# MS SQL removing Duplicates when using DISTINCT/INNER JOINs

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, inner-join, distinct, sql-server-2014

Hey all I am using the following query to get some data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(APL.ProjectID AS nvarchar(4000))         AS ProjectID,
    CAST(APL.StatusOrder AS nvarchar(4000))       AS StatusOrder,
    CAST(APL.DateModified AS nvarchar(4000))      AS DateModified,  
    CAST(APL.PType AS nvarchar(4000))             AS PType,
    CAST(APL.PName AS nvarchar(4000))             AS PName,
    CAST(APL.PostDate AS nvarchar(4000))          AS PostDate,
    CAST(APL.TBillID AS nvarchar(4000))           AS TBillID,
    CAST(APL.Rate AS nvarchar(4000))              AS Rate,
    CAST(APL.Amount AS nvarchar(4000))            AS Amount,
    CAST(P.PContact AS nvarchar(4000))            AS PContact,
    CAST(P.PEMail AS nvarchar(4000))              AS PEMail,
    CAST(P.PPhone AS nvarchar(4000))              AS PPhone,
    CAST(P.PFax AS nvarchar(4000))                AS PFax,
    CAST(APL.CompDate AS nvarchar(4000))          AS CompDate,
    CAST(PS.Comments AS nvarchar(4000))           AS Comments,
    CAST(PS.PSID AS nvarchar(4000))               AS PSID,
    CAST(PS.Status AS nvarchar(4000))             AS Status 
FROM [billing].[dbo].[ActiveProjList]         AS APL 
INNER JOIN [billing].[dbo].[tblPro]           AS P ON APL.ProjectID = P.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN [billing].[dbo].[tblPStatus]       AS PS ON APL.ProjectID = PS.ProjectID
```

However, this returns a record count of **141**. The *correct* records returned should be only **46**.

The column I can use to see if there are any duplicates is **ProjectID**.

Comment: Have you tried using a GROUP BY ProjectID?

Comment: What about other columns? `MIN, MAX, AVG etc.` ?

Comment: @Jonny: If I do that I get the error **Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'ActiveProjList.StatusOrder' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     CAST(APL.ProjectID AS nvarchar(4000))         AS ProjectID,
     MAX(CAST(APL.StatusOrder AS nvarchar(4000)))       AS StatusOrder,
     MAX(CAST(APL.DateModified AS nvarchar(4000)))      AS DateModified,  
     MAX(CAST(APL.PType AS nvarchar(4000)))             AS PType,
     MAX(CAST(APL.PName AS nvarchar(4000)))             AS PName,
     MAX(CAST(APL.PostDate AS nvarchar(4000)))          AS PostDate,
     MAX(CAST(APL.TBillID AS nvarchar(4000)))           AS TBillID,
     MAX(CAST(APL.Rate AS nvarchar(4000)))              AS Rate,
     MAX(CAST(APL.Amount AS nvarchar(4000)))            AS Amount,
     MAX(CAST(P.PContact AS nvarchar(4000)))            AS PContact,
     MAX(CAST(P.PEMail AS nvarchar(4000)))              AS PEMail,
     MAX(CAST(P.PPhone AS nvarchar(4000)))              AS PPhone,
     MAX(CAST(P.PFax AS nvarchar(4000))  )              AS PFax,
     MAX(CAST(APL.CompDate AS nvarchar(4000)))          AS CompDate,
     MAX(CAST(PS.Comments AS nvarchar(4000)))           AS Comments,
     MAX(CAST(PS.PSID AS nvarchar(4000)))               AS PSID,
     MAX(CAST(PS.Status AS nvarchar(4000)))             AS Status 
FROM 
      [billing].[dbo].[ActiveProjList]         AS APL 
INNER JOIN 
      [billing].[dbo].[tblPro]           AS P ON APL.ProjectID = P.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN 
      [billing].[dbo].[tblPStatus]       AS PS ON APL.ProjectID = PS.ProjectID
GROUP BY 
      APL.ProjectID
```

Comment: Boom that was it! Thanks for the help, Jonny!

Comment: I would but cant since **stackoverflow** has a time limit before you can accept the answer :o/

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all columns in the `SELECT`.  Often, the desired result is obtained using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
with t as (
      SELECT CAST(APL.ProjectID AS nvarchar(4000))         AS ProjectID,
             . . .
      FROM [billing].[dbo].[ActiveProjList] APL INNER JOIN
           [billing].[dbo].[tblPro] P
           ON APL.ProjectID = P.ProjectID INNER JOIN
           [billing].[dbo].[tblPStatus] PS
           ON APL.ProjectID = PS.ProjectID
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ProjectId
                                order by datemodified desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This gets the values associated with the most recent `datemodified` value -- which seems like a reasonable approach, given no information about how you want to choose among duplicates.

Comment: Though this did work and was the first reply - it's more cumber-sum than the answer given by Jonny.

Comment: @StealthRT . . . This has the advantage of returning values all from one row, which might not be a requirement for your application.